# How to access subviews in iOS6

Tags: ios6

I create dynamically subviews in my ViewController like this:

```
CGRect imageFrame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024.0, 748.0);
UIImageView *backgroundImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:bgImage];
backgroundImage.frame = imageFrame;
[self.view addSubview:backgroundImage];
```

(Basically, I add various subviews to my view, which are containers for different types of content.)

I am looking for a proper way now, to access these subviews later on, for e.g. fade them out.
Is there a way to add these subviews with an identifier, so I can call them directly ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about UIView's tag property?